# How to capture arguments in a loop, repetitively, in JUnit Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, arguments, mockito

Consider the following situation...

```
public boolean someMethod(List<SomeType> list) {
    for(SomeType someObject: list) {
        if(aMethod(someObject.getId())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want to capture `someObject.getId()` repetitively. If I use something like this...

```
...

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Long> longArgumentCaptor; //Assuming ID is Long
...

when(aMethod(longArgumentCaptor.capture()).thenReturn(true);

assertThat(x.someMethod(Arrays.asList(new SomeType(65L),new SomeType(734L)))).isTrue();

assertThat(longArgumentCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(734L); //<--
...
```

ArgumentCaptor only captures the last value.

However, I want to verify each value. To do that I need to store them. How do I capture every iteration?

Comment: `getAllValues`?

Comment: Ok. That Worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ArgumentCaptor` has a `getAllValues` method for exactly this use-case - it returns a collection of the values from **all** calls to the mock method.

Comment: So, by default ArgumentCaptor captures everything as a list.